# Kafka connect schema registry timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

EDIT: Turns out I turned on a firewall which limited connectivity from containers to host. Adding firewall rules solved the issue.

I am running a kafka JDBC sink connector with the following properties:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "table.name.format": "events",
    "connection.password": "******",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "events",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://IP:PORT",
    "db.buffer.size": "8000000",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "name": "cp-sink-events",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://IP:PORT/postgres?stringtype=unspecified",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.mode": "record_value",
    "pk.fields": "source,timestamp,event,event_type,value"
}
```

It was working fine before, but since this week I have been getting the following errors while trying to sink my data to Postgres:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema for id 4
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

It appears my kafka connect cannot acces my schema registry server anymore. I coulnd't manage to figure out why or how. I have tried multiple things but yet to find the solution.
I did install NGINX on this VM over last week, and killed apache2 which was running on port 80. But I haven't found any dependencies that this would cause any problems.

When I curl the schema registry address from the VM to retrieve the schemas of the mentioned IDs it works fine (http://IP:PORT/schemas/ids/4). any clue how to proceed?

EDIT:
If I configure the IP to random value I get

```
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable).
```

So my host schema registry seems reachable when right IP is configured, I don't know where the timeout limit comes from.

Tried to set timeout limit but didn't work:

```
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TIMEOUT_MS: 10000
```

My compose connect config is set as such:

```
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka0:29092
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect_configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect_offset
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect_status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schemaregistry0:8085
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schemaregistry0:8085
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-connect0
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/usr/share/local-connectors
```

Docker Kafka network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "kafka_default",
        "Id": "89cd2fe68f2ea3923a76ada4dcb89e505c18792e1abe50fa7ad047e10ee6b673",
        "Created": "2023-01-16T18:42:35.531539648+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.25.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.25.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "41ac45882364494a357c26e14f8e3b2aede4ace7eaab3dea748c9a5f94430529": {
                "Name": "kafka-schemaregistry1-1",
                "EndpointID": "56612fbe41396799a8249620dc07b0a5c84c65d311959214b955f538225757ac",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "42c0847ffb7545d35b2d4116fb5c590a869aec87037601d33267a35e7fe0cb2f": {
                "Name": "kafka-kafka-connect0-1",
                "EndpointID": "68eef87346aed70bc17ab9960daca4b24073961dcd93bc85c8f7bcdb714feac3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.8/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "46160f183ba8727fde7b4a7d1770b8d747ed596b8e6b7ca7fea28b39c81dcf7f": {
                "Name": "kafka-zookeeper0-1",
                "EndpointID": "512970666d1c07a632e0f450bef7ceb6aa3281ca648545ef22de4041fe32a845",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "6804e9d36647971afe95f5882e7651e39ff8f76a9537c9c6183337fe6379ced9": {
                "Name": "kafka-ui",
                "EndpointID": "9e9a2a7a04644803703f9c8166d80253258ffba621a5990f3c1efca1112a33a6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:09",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.9/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8b79e3af68df7d405567c896858a863fecf7f2b32d23138fa065327114b7ce83": {
                "Name": "kafka-zookeeper1-1",
                "EndpointID": "d5055748e626f1e00066642a7ef60b6606c5a11a4210d0df156ce532fab4e753",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "92a09c7d3dfb684051660e84793b5328216bf5da4e0ce075d5918c55b9d4034b": {
                "Name": "kafka-kafka0-1",
                "EndpointID": "cbeba237d1f1c752fd9e4875c8694bdd4d85789bcde4d6d3590f4ef95bb82c6f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e8c5aeef7a1a4a2be6ede2e5436a211d87cbe57ca1d8c506d1905d74171c4f6b": {
                "Name": "kafka-kafka1-1",
                "EndpointID": "e310477b655cfc60c846035896a62d32c0d07533bceea2c7ab3d17385fe9507b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ecebbd73e861ed4e2ef8e476fa16d95b0983aaa0876a51b0d292b503ef5e9e54": {
                "Name": "kafka-schemaregistry0-1",
                "EndpointID": "844136d5def798c3837db4256b51c7995011f37576f81d4929087d53a2da7273",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "kafka",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.12.2"
        }
    }
]
```

```
curl http://kafka-schemaregistry0-1:8085/schemas/ids/5
```

Curling the container works from inside the connect container.

EDIT 5:
After changing the URL to the docker container name, I now have access to schema registry.
`"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://kafka-schemaregistry0-1:8085"`

However; now my postgres connection fails.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed
```

I think the conclusion here would be that my connect container was previously able to access containers via the IP of the host machine, and that it now is not able to anymore. I am curious to know how this can be fixed.

Comment: What do you mean "by hand"? Did you curl the registry from the Connect server? In other words, is there a network rule blocking the connection? Why does nginx/apache matter? Are you using them as a reverse proxy?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Correct. When ssh'd to the VM Running kafka, I can curl the schema registry address and retrieve the schemas of the mentioned IDs. Adjusted in the main issue.

I dont think NGINX/Apache would matter, but this is the only thing i have adjusted on the VM since the app started bugging, hence the mention.

Comment: Unless the `PORT` of your config is pointed at those http servers instead, then it wouldn't matter. Have you tried increasing the schema registry client timeout?

Comment: @OneCricketeer so schema registry runs on port 8085, which is the port i also refer to from the connector property above.

I added the following config to my schema registry container:
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TIMEOUT_MS: 10000
Yet I seem to get similar error. I added my connect config in the main issue.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to change the default port? That variable is only the server connection to kafka. You want a connector config under `value.converter.something` to configure the actual registry client

Comment: @OneCricketeer What do you mean changing the default Port? As can be seen in the JDBC sink connector config at the top I do indicate the following: "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://IP:PORT".

Could this error have been caused because I am only converting the values and not the key?

Comment: Schema Registry default port is 8081. You said it's 8085, and you are getting a timeout error, so therefore, are you really connecting to the correct service? Values or keys don't matter; they'd use different instances of the client

Comment: As long as i specify the correct port in value.converter.schema.registry.url the port change shouldnt matter right? I verified the port by curling to the ip+port. I will test tomorrow morning if changing the port could help.

Comment: Are you running the curl command from the Connect container, or from outside? I still believe there is some network policy on your Docker machine that is denying the request and/or causing latency... I looked through the source code for [client config](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/SchemaRegistryClientConfig.java), but I didn't find any timeout properties you can set

Comment: You are absolutely correct; from inside the connect-container I cannot CURL the IP:PORT of the schema-registry container. I am able to CURL the container directly through the docker network though (see network config + command above). After changing the SR URL to CONTAINERNAME:PORT, the connect container was able to access the SR container. However, now I get errors from the postgres side. The conclusion indeed is that my connect container can no longer access IP's outside the docker's network. Any clue how this has been caused and/or can be fixed? @OneCricketeer

Comment: 1) [Never use IP addresses within compose network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) 2) I don't know what your Postgres container setup looks like, but you need to [initialize the database with user grants](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#initialization-scripts)